# Crud application wont instert into database

Tags: php, html, sql

my application wont insert into database, and its not giving me any errors.
If my question is a duplicate, please redirect me to the original question, thanks.

MY PHP CODE:

```
<?php
include_once("dbconfig.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    /*$targetDir = "slike/";
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');
    $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';*/
    $image = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['ime']);
    $group=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['grupa']);
    $semi=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['podgrupa']);
    $price=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['cena']);
    if(empty($name) || empty($group) || empty($semi)||empty($price)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Namesteno je da sve moraju da budu popunjene.</font><br/>";

        if(empty($name)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Ime je prazno.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($group)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Grupa je prazna.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($semi)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Podgrupa je prazna.</font><br/>";
        }
        if(empty($price)){
            echo "<font color='red'>Cena je prazna.</font><br/>";
        }
    }
    else{

       $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO slike(ime,grupa,podgrupa,cena,slika) VALUES('$name','$group','$semi','$price','$file')");

       echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
}
}


  ?>
```

My html:

```
  </div>
    <div class="content">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Slike biras ovde:
        <input type="file" name="files">
        <p>IME</p>
        <input type="text" name="ime">
        <p>GRUPA</p>
        <input type="text" name="grupa">
        <p>PODGRUPA</p>
        <input type="text" name="podgrupa">
        <p>CENA</p>
        <input type="text" name="cena">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPISI">
    </form>
```

If you need some more codes i will post it in replies.
Problem is that i get the message "Data added successfully"
But when i go to the database, its empty.
THANKS to anyone who helps me.

Comment: you just print `Data added successfully` never check it ?

Comment: I check it but its not added.

Comment: no i mean you should handle errors properly using `$result` value

Comment: mysql returns errors differently than PHP. You have to explicitly check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Can you provide your including dbconfig code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
$host="localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="slikezasajt";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
 or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

//$mysqli->close();
?>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/your_php_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Please set action to your form which should go to your php file.

Comment: Sorry, but it didnt help
Still the same problem. :(